# Go GORM Mocking Begin Expected

Tags: unit-testing, go, go-gorm, go-sqlmock

I am trying to test a function that gets some details then update details in db. I am using gorm for my ORM and mocking db exec with DATA-DOG/sqlmock. But I keep getting expected begin error but not sure where I am messing up. I tried many variations of the code where I remove the expectBegin expectCommit etc.

Here is the code I am trying to test:

```
// UpsertUserProfile saves the user if doesn't exists and adds the OAuth profile
// and updates existing user info if record exist in db
func (o *ORM) UpsertUserProfile(gu *goth.User) (*models.User, error) {
    db := o.DB
    up := &models.UserProfile{}
    u, err := models.GothUserToDBUser(gu, false)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    tx := db.Where("email = ?", gu.Email).First(u)
    if tx.Error != nil && tx.Error != gorm.ErrRecordNotFound {
        return nil, tx.Error
    }

    if tx := db.Model(u).Save(u); tx.Error != nil {
        return nil, tx.Error
    }

    tx = db.Where("email = ? AND provider = ? AND external_user_id = ?", gu.Email, gu.Provider, gu.UserID).First(up)
    if tx.Error != nil && tx.Error != gorm.ErrRecordNotFound {
        return nil, tx.Error
    }

    up, err = models.GothUserToDBUserProfile(gu, false)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    up.User = *u
    if tx := db.Model(up).Save(up); tx.Error != nil {
        return nil, tx.Error
    }
    return u, nil
}
```

And here is the test code

```
func TestORM_UpsertUserProfile(t *testing.T) {
    mockdb, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("an error '%s' was not expected when opening a stub database connection", err)
    }
    gormDB, err := gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        Conn: mockdb,
    }), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    defer mockdb.Close()

    id, _ := uuid.NewV4()

    rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"id", "first_name", "last_name"}).
        AddRow(id.String(), "fname", "lname")
    profileRows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"email"}).AddRow("email")

    // Test cases
    t.Run("success", func(t *testing.T) {
        o := &ORM{
            DB: gormDB,
        }
        now := time.Now()
        fName := "fname"
        lName := "lname"
        wantUsr := models.User{
            Email:     "email",
            FirstName: &fName,
            LastName:  &lName,
            BaseModelSoftDelete: models.BaseModelSoftDelete{
                BaseModel: models.BaseModel{
                    ID:        id,
                    CreatedAt: &now,
                    UpdatedAt: &now,
                },
            },
        }

        mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta(`SELECT * FROM "users"`)).WithArgs("email").WillReturnRows(rows)
        mock.ExpectBegin()
        mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta(`UPDATE`)).WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
        mock.ExpectCommit()
        mock.ExpectBegin()
        mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta(`SELECT * FROM "user_profiles"`)).WithArgs("email", "provider", "testID").WillReturnRows(profileRows)
        mock.ExpectCommit()
        mock.ExpectBegin()

        got, err := o.UpsertUserProfile(&goth.User{Email: "email", UserID: "testID", Provider: "provider"})
        if (err != nil) != false {
            t.Errorf("ORM.UpsertUserProfile() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, false)
            return
        }
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, wantUsr) {
            t.Errorf("ORM.UpsertUserProfile() = %v, want %v", got, wantUsr)
        }
    })
}
```

but the test keeps returning this error

```
SELECT * FROM "user_profiles" WHERE email = 'email' AND provider = 'provider' AND external_user_id = 'testID' ORDER BY "user_profiles"."id" LIMIT 1
    /Users/public/Projects/go-rest-service/internal/orm/orm_test.go:260: ORM.UpsertUserProfile() error = call to Query 'SELECT * FROM "user_profiles" WHERE email = $1 AND provider = $2 AND external_user_id = $3 ORDER BY "user_profiles"."id" LIMIT 1' with args [{Name: Ordinal:1 Value:email} {Name: Ordinal:2 Value:provider} {Name: Ordinal:3 Value:testID}], was not expected, next expectation is: ExpectedBegin => expecting database transaction Begin, wantErr false
```

Comment: The func you want to test is doing the following (if no error occurs): `select, update, select, update`. Gorm seemingly, and understandably, wraps each update in a transaction, and, also understandably, it does *not* wrap the selects in a transaction. So the full set of executed instructions is as follows: `select, being, update, commit, select, begin, update, commit`. Your test's `ExpectXxx` function calls should reflect that.

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html: *"GORM perform write (create/update/delete) operations run inside a transaction to ensure data consistency"* -- you can see that select is not on the list since it is not a write operation. So doing `ExpectBeing();ExpectQuery("select ...");ExpectCommit()` is a mistake.

Comment: got it, adding this pattern solved kinda solved the issue mentioned in the ticket

Comment: now I get `call to Rollback transaction, was not expected, next expectation is: ExpectedExec => expecting Exec or ExecContext which:` after adding in the missing `begin`, `update`, `commit`.

Comment: ```mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta(`SELECT * FROM "users"`)).WithArgs("email").WillReturnRows(rows)
  mock.ExpectBegin()
  mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta(`UPDATE`)).WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
  mock.ExpectCommit()
  mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta(`SELECT * FROM "user_profiles"`)).WithArgs("email", "provider", "testID").WillReturnRows(profileRows)
  mock.ExpectBegin()
  mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta(`INSERT INTO "users"`)).WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
  mock.ExpectCommit()```

Comment: I assume rollback is called automatically by gorm if a query within a transaction fails, so you need to figure out what failed and why, fix it, and retry.

Comment: got it thanks a lot